# Can I eat carrots with wormholes in them?

Tags: plant-health, root-vegetables, safety, carrots, worms

I started cleaning up and cutting two big carrots to make a soup when I realized worms had dug galleries in them. Is it safe to eat them even if I clean them? So far I have not found any worms but can I be certain that there aren't any that I have missed?

Thank you all in advance for your insight!

Answer (score 7):

Chop the carrots up, just to make sure. They're most likely holes left by larvae of the carrot fly, and they may long have left and turned into flies. Even if you do inadvertently cook one in the soup, consider it an extra bit of protein, it won't harm you, although if you're vegetarian, you might want to slice them quite finely to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

If it were just me eating them I would cut them in about 1/4 inch chunks.  If I were cooking them for someone else I would do a finer dice cut looking for the trail and make sure all damaged/unsightly bits were removed.  I keep worm buckets for food scraps and they love bits of carrot.